# Error java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String ,while using Javascript windowhandles

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, arraylist

I am using below JS code to handle different windows during execution, but i am getting following error "java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String"

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
            browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);

//Performing actions
       });
```

Comment: your error is a server exception.... :)
 java.lang.String (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: So can you please let me know what changes has to be done for handling it..

Comment: fix the bug in your server code (Java not JavaScript)

Comment: So your telling that is a Java code not JS is it ?

Comment: right: 1st javascript is a dynamically typed language. 2nd the error message contains references to the Java-API (e.g. java.lang)